# Angular 2+ can't find Angular 1.X to bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I'm trying to bootstrap an Angular 1.X app with Angular 2+ (Angular 4.1.0 at the time of writing this question). I followed the [online guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) to the T but can't seem to make headway.

I'm using a hybrid of ES2015+ (compiled via Babel) and TypeScript. Everything compiles correctly and I can run both Angular 1 and Angular 2 separately successfully. They get compiled together using Webpack if that makes a difference.

Here's what my Angular 1.X entry file (`app.ts`) approximately looks like:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

export default angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function() { console.log('Angular 1 is running!')})
```

For simplicity sake, I deleted all dependencies from the main application so that I can be sure it's not the run/config function or one of the dependencies. I have tested with config/run functions to see if any of those run or throw errors but they don't.

I then have an entry file for my Angular 2+ app (that I use as an entry file for Webpack as well) called `main.ts` which looks like this:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import app from '../app/app';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  console.log('angular 2+ bootstrapped');
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  console.log('getting update module');
  console.log('app', app)
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [app.name], { strictDi: true})
   console.log('should be bootstrapped')
})
```

The process fails after the `console.log('app', app)` line. The log shows that `app` is, indeed, an instance of the Angular 1.X app. But the bootstrap process still fails.

Any ideas on what I'm not doing right?

**EDIT**

Here is my `app.module` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(protected upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}
  ngDoBootstrap() {
  }
};
```

**EDIT2**

My hunch is that Angular 2+ depends on AngularJS 1.X to be already on the window object. I'm running AngularJS 1.X from within a module. I'll update as I work on it. I answered a few comments below. Currently, I'm using as simple of an example as possible and for AngularJS 1.X, I'm literally running a barebones app that logs out if it's been bootstrapped via `.run`

**EDIT 3**

I posted an answer below. What it boiled down to was the ordering of imports in the `main.ts` file (the entry file). Simply importing the AngularJS 1.X app before importing `zone.js` fixed the issue.

Comment: I got rid of Babel and Webpack, same issue. The test case is as I describe it above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question (and thus not give credit to everyone that helped, thank you!) but here is what fixed it.

I changed the order of imports in `main.ts` the entry file! :)

Here's what the new version looks like:

```
import app from '../app/app.temp';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  console.log('angular 2+ bootstrapped');
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  console.log('getting update module');
  console.log('app', app)
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [app.name], { strictDi: true})
   console.log('should be bootstrapped')
})
```

I basically just had to import the AngularJS 1.X app before `zone.js`. I'm not sure why that is but it worked flawlessly.

**EDIT**

I filed an issue on Angular's repo and got an "official" answer. It works on 4.1.0-rc.0 and above. There is a method to manually set a reference to AngularJS instead of having the system try to get it from the `window` object. As it is, AngularJS seems to attach itself to `window` when it runs even when it's bundled; however, it does so "too late" (which is why my fix works).

So here's what you can do:

```
import { setAngularLib } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import * as angular from 'angular';

setAngularLib(angular);
// do your bootstrap here
```

Comment: You could have also done this, enforcing order for older scripts.  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Comment: the problem is that I want to cross-pollinate the components so that I can transition the apps much more easily. I'd rather do that using imports/requires rather than depend on global access to AngularJS

Comment: After reading your blog I kinda get why you went that way.  Wanting to use Angular2 code for most of your new problems while leaving legacy stuff in the old angularJS.  Its going to be a messy downhill problem but have fun.

Comment: @James my blog? I don't think I've mentioned anything on there about transitioning. But thanks for reading anyways! :)